# Prism and importing controls into regions

Tags: prism, region

When using Prism to inject controls into regions,

Is it possible to inject a control that has been initialized with certain properties?
Problem is in using XAML I cant inherit from the control and assign different properties and it seems in using Prism I have to use the default constructor in injecting in the control into the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Navigation framework to inject controls into regions then you can implement `INavigationAware` and pass some parameters as query string.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2010/10/04/prism-v4-region-navigation-pipeline.aspx